# parallel Bitonic sort mpi

Tags: c, mpi

i'm trying to do a parallel bitonic sort using mpi and C but i obtained a deadlock or any other block state when send e recv array in comp_exchange_max or in comp_exchange_min function. can you help me to resolve this problem? thanks

```
void comp_exchange_max(int j, int rank, int *local_numbers, int dim_array, int *ordered_array)
{
    int message_receive[dim_array];
    int i, k, q;
    if (rank > 0)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&message_receive, dim_array, MPI_INT, rank ^ (1 << j), 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        MPI_Send(local_numbers, dim_array, MPI_INT, rank ^ (1 << j), 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    /* comparison */
    k = dim_array - 1;
    q = dim_array - 1;
    for (i = dim_array - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (local_numbers[k] > message_receive[q])
        {
            ordered_array[i] = local_numbers[k];
            --k;
        }
        else
        {
            ordered_array[i] = message_receive[q];
            --q;
        }
    }
}

void comp_exchange_min(int j, int rank, int *local_numbers, int dim_array, int *ordered_array)
{
    int message_receive[dim_array];
    int i, k, q;
    if (rank > 0)
    {
        MPI_Send(local_numbers, dim_array, MPI_INT, rank ^ (1 << j), 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Recv(&message_receive, dim_array, MPI_INT, rank ^ (1 << j), 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
    /* comparison */
    k = 0;
    q = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < dim_array; ++i)
    {
        if (local_numbers[k] < message_receive[q])
        {
            ordered_array[i] = local_numbers[k];
            ++k;
        }
        else
        {
            ordered_array[i] = message_receive[q];
            ++q;
        }
    }
}
```

all code is here https://pastebin.com/DrR5SGxv

Comment: That could be a deadlock (e.g. all processes are stuck in `MPI_Recv()` so no one can `MPI_Send()`. Try using `MPI_Sendrecv()` and see if it helps.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet it doesn't work. again deadlock

Comment: how many MPI tasks are you using? did you print who is talking to who? are you sure no one ever tries to talk to rank `0`?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I added some stamps before MPI_Sendrecv and i obtain this:   ```mpirun --allow-run-as-root -np 4 ./a.out
9 12 7 11 14 12 12 8 2 8 8 3 12 11 0 4
i am: 1 and my next is: 0

i am: 2 and my next is: 3

i am: 2 and my next is: 0

i am: 3 and my next is: 2

i am: 3 and my next is: 1```.                                                                                     
and then deadlock

Comment: “i am: 1 and my next is: 0“, see my previous comment.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet why i can't talk to rank 0?

Comment: and how can i resolve?

Comment: Rank 1 communicates with rank 0, but rank 0 is deaf and mute.